# insert user's data from FQL into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get user's data from my PHP app and then store those data into my database. Before i upload my app into Facebook i wanted to know if this form of code is written okay.
 Below is the code that i used.

```
<head>
<?php
require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

$config = array(
'appId' => 'xxxx',
'secret' => 'xxxxxx',

);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
if($user_id) {

  // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
  // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
  try {
    $fql = 'SELECT name, first_name, last_name, birthday_date, sex, 
education, locale, activities from user where uid = ' . $user_id;
    $ret_obj = $facebook->api(array(
                               'method' => 'fql.query',
                               'query' => $fql,
                             ));

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(firstname, lastname, birthday, sex,
 education, local, activities) VALUES($ret_obj['first_name'], $ret_obj['last_name'],
 $ret_obj['birthday_date'], $ret_obj['sex'], $ret_obj['education'], 
$ret_obj['locale'], $ret_obj['activities']) ");
    // FQL queries return the results in an array, so we have
    //  to get the user's name from the first element in the array.
    echo '<pre>Name: ' . $ret_obj[0]['name'] . '</pre>';

  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
    // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
    // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
    // just ask the user to login again here.
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   
 } else {

  // No user, so print a link for the user to login
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

}

?>
</body>
```

Comment: Please read the Big warning part of [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for `mysql_query`.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it. But i don't know if the other part (insert part) is okay?